# What's the difference here?

Tags: bash

I have written a script to automate a routine, but can't understand the difference between the 2 blocks below. The first works and the second doesn't.

This works:

```
echo "$(pull_data)" > data.csv

cat data.csv | while read a b c d; do
```

This doesn't work:

```
cat "$(pull_data)" | while read a b c d; do
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat` concatenates and outputs files - I think you want `echo` in your second statement:

```
echo "$(pull_data)" | while read a b c d; do
```

Comment: By contrast, `cat <<< "$(pull_data)" | ...` should work, as it allows `cat` to read from standard input, which is provided data from the `pull_data` command. `cat < <( pull_data ) | ...` would also work for the same reason via a different mechanism, namely process substitution instead of a here string.

Comment: Also, the `echo` is unnecessary in this case, because you could simply pipe `pull_data | ...` directly.

Answer (score 2):

`cat` is used to work with files. You don't have a file in this case. If you don't need to store your data in `data.csv`, you should be able to pipe it directly to the loop:

```
echo "$(pull_data)" | while read a b c d; do
```